# ACF Google Maps field not rendering

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to use a google maps field from ACF in my site.  I have an api key and am using the example code. I can see the block element on the page but there is not content.

I am getting the following error

```
google-maps.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
at render_map (google-maps.js:24)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (google-maps.js:151)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2)
at o.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (google-maps.js:149)
at j (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2)
at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2)
```

I am using the code as found here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/ but have replaced the xxx with my own api key
here is the code

```
    /*
*  new_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function new_map( $el ) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');


    // vars
    var args = {
        zoom        : 16,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };


    // create map               
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);


    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];


    // add markers
    $markers.each(function(){

        add_marker( $(this), map );

    });


    // center map
    center_map( map );


    // return
    return map;

}

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open( map, marker );

        });
    }

}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

    // vars
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

        bounds.extend( latlng );

    });

    // only 1 marker?
    if( map.markers.length == 1 )
    {
        // set center of map
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        map.setZoom( 16 );
    }
    else
    {
        // fit to bounds
        map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }

}

/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/
// global var
var map = null;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function(){

        // create map
        map = new_map( $(this) );

    });

});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I am enqueueing the js as described in this tutorial  https://www.aliciaramirez.com/2015/02/advanced-custom-fields-google-maps-tutorial/
I am fairly new to working with js and new to apis so I might have missed something really obvious.

Comment: Can you share a link to the page where we can see this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>`
and if it's already in the code, you need to make sure it's in the header (needs to run before your code).

Comment: I've moved further with this now.  I can see the maps now but having trouble with the long and lat not being recongnised from acf.  going to check a few things and if i'm still having trouble i'll be back with an online verison to show.  thanks